# Simple Condition For Void

Tags: c#, combobox, switch-statement

i have 2 controls for highlighting, and separated void control like:

```
public void yee()
{
    rtb.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

public void yoo()
{
    rtb.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

then I have a combobox which have an item of:

yee and yoo .

when I select yee the void yee should be selected but when I select yoo the void yoo should be selected.

I know its kinda easy but i need the condition to be "case" instead of "if" since I want to have break, and if it's possible make the void = false if one got selected .

Thanks a lot! and sorry for this newbie question .xD

Comment: Can `void == false;`?

Comment: BTW, those are called _functions_.  (or methods)

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  What are you trying to write?

Comment: @SLaks switchcase for void using combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still unclear what you are trying to do, but if you are wanting to add a switch statement to determine which method that you need to run, assign it to your `ComboBox's` `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectedValueChanged` EventHandlers.

See if something like this is what you are wanting.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower()) //Have to get the string representation 
    {                                                               //since Selected Item is an object
        case "yee":
            yee();
            break;
        case "yoo":
            yoo();
            break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but this is my best stab at it. Note `DropDownList1` is the `ID` of your DDL.

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "yee"){
    yee();
}

if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "yoo"){
    yoo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just do a bool function

such as

```
 public boolean yeeOrYooPressed() {
 {
     if(//yee is selected) {
           return true;
     }
     else {
           return false;
           break;
     }
  }
```